# why does applying probability distributions and transformations result in the same value?

Tags: python, pandas, probability-distribution

I'm applying multiple Beta, Gamma and HalfNorm Transforms to each column of my pandas dataframe. The dataframe consists of marketing spend; each row indicates spend per week and each column indicates type of spend:
[image]

The python functions and code to apply the transform is as follows:

```
def geometric_adstock_tt(
    x, alpha=0, L=12, normalize=True
):  # 12 (days) is the delay or lag we expect to see?
    """
    The term "geometric" refers to the way weights are assigned to past values,
    which follows a geometric progression.
    In a geometric progression,
    each term is found by multiplying the previous term by a fixed, constant ratio (commonly denoted as "r").
    In the case of the geometric adstock function, the "alpha" parameter serves as this constant ratio.
    """
    # vector of weights assigned by decay rate alpha set to be 12 weeks
    w = np.array([alpha**i for i in range(L)])
    xx = np.stack(
        [np.concatenate([np.zeros(i), x[: x.shape[0] - i]]) for i in range(L)]
    )

    if not normalize:
        y = np.dot(w, xx)
    else:
        y = np.dot(
            w / np.sum(w), xx
        )  # dot product to get marketing channel over time frame of decay
    return y


### non-linear saturation function
def logistic_function(x_t, mu=0.1):
    # apply the logistic function to spend variable
    return (1 - np.exp(-mu * x_t)) / (1 * np.exp(-mu * x_t))

#################
response_mean = []
# Create Distributions
halfnorm_dist = st.halfnorm(loc=0, scale=5)
# Create a beta distribution
beta_dist = st.beta(a=3, b=3)
# Create a gamma distribution
gamma_dist = st.gamma(a=3)

delay_channels = [
    'TV', 'Referral', 'DirectMail', 'TradeShows', 'SocialMedia','DisplayAds_Standard', 'ContentMarketing',
       'GoogleAds', 'SEO', 'Email', 'AffiliateMarketing',
]
non_lin_channels = ["DisplayAds_Programmatic"]
################ ADSTOCK CHANNELS
for channel_name in delay_channels:
    xx = df_in[channel_name].values
    print(f"Adding Delayed Channels: {channel_name}")

    # apply beta transform
    y = beta_dist.pdf(xx)

    # apply geometric adstock transform
    geo_transform = geometric_adstock_tt(y)

    # apply gamma transform
    z = gamma_dist.pdf(geo_transform)

    # apply logistic function transform
    log_transform = logistic_function(z)

    # apply halfnorm transform
    output = halfnorm_dist.pdf(geo_transform)
    
    # append output
    response_mean.append(list(output))
    
################# SATURATION ONLY
for channel_name in non_lin_channels:
    xx = df_in[channel_name].values
    
    # apply gamma transform
    z = gamma_dist.pdf(xx)

    # apply logistic function transform
    log_transform = logistic_function(z)

    # apply halfnorm transform
    output = halfnorm_dist.pdf(log_transform)
    
    # append output
    response_mean.append(list(output))
```

[image]

I'm not quite understanding why all values are being transformed to the same value. I would be so appreciative of any insight! Thanks so much:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what's happening is that the beta distribution you defined expects your data to be in the range 0 ≤ x ≤ 1 (see the [notes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html#scipy.stats.beta) for the beta distribution documentation), and anything outside of this range will have a pdf value of 0.

So one possibility is to first min-max scale all of your columns to be in the range 0-1 using the following:

```
df_in = (df_in-df_in.min())/(df_in.max()-df_in.min())
```

Using some made up data:

```
delay_channels = [
    'TV', 'Referral', 'DirectMail', 'TradeShows', 'SocialMedia','DisplayAds_Standard', 'ContentMarketing',
       'GoogleAds', 'SEO', 'Email', 'AffiliateMarketing',
]
non_lin_channels = ["DisplayAds_Programmatic"]

sample_dates = pd.date_range('2023-01-01','2024-01-01',freq='7D')
sample_data_dict = {
    channel: 1000 + 100*np.random.rand(53) for channel in delay_channels+non_lin_channels
}
sample_data_dict['Date'] = sample_dates
np.random.seed(42)
df_in = pd.DataFrame(sample_data_dict)
df_in = df_in.set_index('Date')
df_in = (df_in-df_in.min())/(df_in.max()-df_in.min())
```

After applying your transformations, I get the following:

[image]

Comment: That was it @Derek. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome - happy to have helped!